# Rendering UIView as pdf not working in iOS 17

Tags: pdf, uiview, pdfkit

Below code used to work properly before iOS 17. But now it is hanging on drawHierarchy function. Have tried with `pdfView.layer.render(in: context.cgContext)` function also instead of `drawHierarchy`. But still UI hangs. This method cannot be called from background thread.

```
let render = UIGraphicsPDFRenderer(bounds: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
try render.writePDF(to: path, withActions: { context in
                        context.beginPage()
                        pdfView.drawHierarchy(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height), afterScreenUpdates: true)
                        completion(true, path)
                    })
```

Is there any solution to this problem? I have tried using `ImageRenderer` of swiftUI. But contents of scrollviews are rendered blank.

Comment: I have the same issue. Is pdfView rendered on screen or separately created for the pdf?